# Convert two loops to a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a list comprehension for lines 3-6 of the function. It returns the relevant restaurant(s) depending on the choice in `guests_diet`. The result should be the string "Sorry, no restaurants meet your restrictions". The function works but I'm being challenged to do the list comprehension. I came up with the code below but I'm getting an incorrect result. Can anyone help?

Tried code producing incorrect results -

```
ans = [restaurant.append(key) for key, value in rest_names.items()\
                  for x in range(len(cuisine)) if cuisine[x] in value]
```

Code -

```
def no_you_pick(rest_names, cuisine):
    restaurant = []
    for key, value in rest_names.items():
        for x in range(len(cuisine)):
            if cuisine[x] in value:
                restaurant.append(key)
    restaurant.sort()
    if len(restaurant) == 0:
        return "Sorry, no restaurants meet your restrictions"
    elif len(restaurant) == 1:
        return ' '.join(restaurant)
    return ', '.join(restaurant)

grading_scale = {"blossom": ["vegetarian", "vegan", "kosher", "gluten-free", "dairy-free"], \
             "jacob's pickles": ["vegetarian", "gluten-free"], \
             "sweetgreen": ["vegetarian", "vegan", "gluten-free", "kosher"]}
guests_diet = ["buttered-lobster"]
print(no_you_pick(grading_scale, guests_diet))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work -

```
def no_you_pick(rest_names, cuisine):
    restaurant = [key for key,value in rest_names.items() for x in range(len(cuisine)) if cuisine[x] in value]
    restaurant.sort()
    if len(restaurant) == 0:
        return "Sorry, no restaurants meet your restrictions"
    elif len(restaurant) == 1:
        return ' '.join(restaurant)
    return ', '.join(restaurant)

grading_scale = {"blossom": ["vegetarian", "vegan", "kosher", "gluten-free", "dairy-free"], \
             "jacob's pickles": ["vegetarian", "gluten-free"], \
             "sweetgreen": ["vegetarian", "vegan", "gluten-free", "kosher"]}
guests_diet = ["buttered-lobster"]
print(no_you_pick(grading_scale, guests_diet))
print(no_you_pick(grading_scale, ['vegan']))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Sorry, no restaurants meet your restrictions
blossom, sweetgreen
```

---

You don't need to append to the `restaurant` .

> ```
> ans = [restaurant.append(key) for key, value in rest_names.items() for x in range(len(cuisine)) if cuisine[x] in value]
> ```

Since you are using list comprehension, you can directly build your list - `restaurant` and only the keys that match the given condition would be added in the list. Here, instead of writing `restaurant.append(key)`, you can easily directly append keys using list comprehension on `restaurant` as done in the above code

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this with the following list comprehension:

```py
restaurant = [key for key, value in rest_names.items()\
              if any(item in cuisine for item in value)]
```

And no need to declare `restaurant` to be an empty list above it.